# Search and replace next n words in vi

Tags: vim, vi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vim :s replace first N < g occurrences on a line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27178/vim-s-replace-first-n-g-occurrences-on-a-line)

In vi, how do I search and replace a word's first `n` occurrences with a word, say "hello", and the next `m` occurrences with `bonjour`, and all the rest with `namaste`?

Comment: Just a note: the linked question restricts the occurrences to a single line whereas this question seems to be asking about the whole file.  However the same techniques would apply by simply prepending a range of `%` to any `:s` command in any of the answers there.

Answer (score 0):

Can you locate the nth "hello" manually? If so, then, I would locate the nth hello as follows:

```
:1 (goes to the first line of your file)
n/hello (find the nth hello, where n is the number)
```

Then substitute all the hellos as follows:

```
:1,.s/hello/bonjour/g
(move to the next line)
:.,$s/hello/namaste/g
```

Comment: @Kevin thanks. I was thinking one thing and typed another. I've corrected my answer replacing `.` with `n`.

Comment: Yep, that'll work. Not to nag, but `/` [and `n` for that matter] takes an argument, so `5/hello` will find the fifth occurrence of `hello`.

Comment: @Kevin thanks, yeah, you're right. You beat me to it as I was just looking that up.

Comment: How does one "move to the next line" in vi?  I cannot seem to figure that part out.

Comment: @ChrisBoone there are several ways to move to the next line in `vi`: (1) press `Enter` or `Return`, (2) press `Down Arrow` or `j` key.

Comment: @StephenQuan Perhaps I am in an older version of `vi`, but pressing `Enter` or `Return` just sends the command I am entering.  I will try the other method.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This basically boils down to the same as my question (linked in the comments; as mentioned, mine asks about a single line but is trivially generalized to more).  The easiest answer is `:%s/hello/first/gc`, hit `y` n times and then `q`, `:%s/hello/second/gc`, `y` m times and `q`, etc.  If you need more than a few, use  `feedkeys` and `repeat` as outlined in the accepted answer there.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun! FUN(n, m)
    if !exists('g:count')
        let g:count = 0
    endif

    let g:count+=1

    if g:count<=a:n
        return 'hello'
    elseif g:count<=a:n+a:m
        return 'bonjour'
    else
        return 'namaste'
    endif
endfun
```

---

```
:unlet! g:count
:%s/word/\=FUN(2, 3)/g
```

---

### before

```
word
word
word
word
word
word
word
```

### after

```
hello
hello
bonjour
bonjour
bonjour
namaste
namaste
```